# Copy paste values in Excel multiple selections

Tags: excel, copy, paste

I have tried to make multiple selections in an excel sheet where there are formulas in each cell that is highlighted as shown below. I have tried copy/paste these cells, so they only show hardcoded values instead of formulas. Unfortunately, Excel doesn't allow this type of action when you have multiple selections. Is there a way to have multiple selections (as shown below) in Excel and copy only the selected cells and then paste the values with only having to use the paste special option once?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any other way than using VBA in this case.

This code worked for me:

```
Sub myPasteSpecial()
  Dim cell As Range
  
  For Each cell In Selection
    cell.Value = cell.Value
  Next cell
  
End Sub
```